# window.location.hash difference write url and a tag

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, masonry

html code

```
<div class="fakeSearch">
    <input id="searchInput" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    <img id="searchImg" class="clickAble" src="./img/search.png">
</div>
```

script

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", ChangePage);

$('#searchImg').on('click', function(){
  var word = decodeURIComponent($('#searchInput').val());
  window.location.hash = '#search:'+word;
});

var ChangePage = function(){
  var myUrl = window.location.hash;
  var argStr = myUrl.split("\\");
  argStr = argStr[0].split(":");
  argStr[0] = argStr[0].replace("#", "");

  $('#mainPlace > div').css('display','none');

  if(myUrl === ""){}
  ...
  else if(argStr[0]==='search'){
    $('#searchPage').css('display','block');
    InitLoadSearch(decodeURIComponent(argStr[1]));
  }
}

var InitLoadSearch = function(){
   /* call ajax data and print masonry */
}
```

work when write direct typing url  **#search:123** 
but, **window.location.hash = '#search:'+word** code is not work.
more correct, default page is masonry page.
*masonry - i use http://masonry.desandro.com/  
also search page is masonry page.
grids of default page is break.(position reset), when search click and back button click
break in only **android mobile chrome**
each grid is other define.

additionally,

```
<a href="#search:code"></a>
```

is normal work! only

```
window.location.hash = "#search:"+variable;
```

is break.

in conclusion, i know difference **write url, a tag href** and **window.location.hash**

Comment: a tag is https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#adef-href  i want know window.location ! T^T... in each broswer(SpiderMonkey, Rhino... etc) or ECMA

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you are difficult to understand.

I've tried your code in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3ouLyxds/ and it seems to work. I only changed the order of the code, or it wouldn't work at all:

```
var ChangePage = function(){

  var myUrl = window.location.hash;
  var argStr = myUrl.split("\\");
  argStr = argStr[0].split(":");
  argStr[0] = argStr[0].replace("#", "");

  $('#mainPlace > div').css('display','none');

if(argStr[0]==='search'){
    $('#searchPage').css('display','block');
    InitLoadSearch(decodeURIComponent(argStr[1]));
  }
}

var InitLoadSearch = function(str){
   alert(str);
}

window.addEventListener("hashchange", ChangePage);

$('#searchImg').on('click', function(){
  var word = decodeURIComponent($('#searchInput').val());
  window.location.hash = '#search:'+word;
});
```

Comment: Thank you feedback! masonry break in mobile chrome( when use script - window open, location href, location hash  etc...)<br>only normal work when <a href="">. then i want know difference script url and html tag url